# Can't force IE8 Document Mode in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Can anyone tell me why the following would fail to trigger IE8 Document mode in IE9? The developer toolbar shows IE9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Nothing to see here.    
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=8') ignored because document mode is already finalized.